# tablelayout not having equal width

Tags: android

I am using this code, but the center column is having more width than others. i tried removing rows, it seems the problem is row2 & row4. but there is no padding or margin but still its not proper.

```
        <!-- title row 1 -->

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeLabletv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_time_spend"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/focusLabletv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_focus"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caloriesLabel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_calories"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- data row 1 -->
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeSpenttv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="8.00M"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/focusValuetv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_focus_balance"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/caloriestv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_calories_def"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- title row 2 -->

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/setsLabletv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_sets"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/repetitionsLabletv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_reps"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kilosLabel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_kilos"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- data row 2 -->

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/setsValuetv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_sets_def"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/repetitionsValuetv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_reps_def"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kilostv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/tr_kilos_def"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: data row 1, second textview: `layout_width ="wrap_content"`. Why?

Comment: @Geobits tried with "match_parent" and "fill_parent" as well.but didn't work

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the field widths to 0 and the weights to "1" and it sets all three columns to equal widths.  Like this:

```
<TableRow>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeLabletv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_time_spend"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/focusLabletv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_focus"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/caloriesLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_calories"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

        <!-- data row 1 -->
<TableRow>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeSpenttv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="8.00M"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/focusValuetv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_focus_balance"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/caloriestv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_calories_def"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

        <!-- title row 2 -->

<TableRow>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/setsLabletv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_sets"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/repetitionsLabletv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_reps"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/kilosLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_kilos"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

        <!-- data row 2 -->

<TableRow>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/setsValuetv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_sets_def"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/repetitionsValuetv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_reps_def"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/kilostv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/tr_kilos_def"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```